# Basic Authentication for Grizzly Server

Tags: java, basic-authentication, grizzly

I have implemented this example into my application:

[https-clientserver-grizzly](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/show/trunk/jersey/samples/https-clientserver-grizzly?rev=5752)

Here is *Server.java* from that link:

```
public class Server {

    private static HttpServer webServer;

    public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();
    public static final String CONTENT = "JERSEY HTTPS EXAMPLE\n";

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("https://localhost/").port(getPort(4463)).build();
    }

    private static int getPort(int defaultPort) {
        String port = System.getProperty("jersey.test.port");
        if (null != port) {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(port);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
        }
        return defaultPort;
    }

    protected static void startServer() {

        // add Jersey resource servlet
        WebappContext context = new WebappContext("context");
        ServletRegistration registration = 
                context.addServlet("ServletContainer", ServletContainer.class);
        registration.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
                "com.sun.jersey.samples.https_grizzly.resource;com.sun.jersey.samples.https_grizzly.auth");

        // add security filter (which handles http basic authentication)
        registration.setInitParameter(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS,
                SecurityFilter.class.getName());

        // Grizzly ssl configuration
        SSLContextConfigurator sslContext = new SSLContextConfigurator();

        // set up security context
        sslContext.setKeyStoreFile("./keystore_server"); // contains server keypair
        sslContext.setKeyStorePass("asdfgh");
        sslContext.setTrustStoreFile("./truststore_server"); // contains client certificate
        sslContext.setTrustStorePass("asdfgh");

        try {

            webServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                    getBaseURI(),
                    null,
                    true,
                    new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslContext).setClientMode(false).setNeedClientAuth(true)
            );

            // start Grizzly embedded server //
            System.out.println("Jersey app started. Try out " + BASE_URI + "\nHit CTRL + C to stop it...");
            context.deploy(webServer);
            webServer.start();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected static void stopServer() {
        webServer.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        startServer();

        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

However I decided to enable just Basic Authentication (not SSl authentication needed)

I changed that part:

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(getPort(4463)).build();
```

and I commented the part from that line:

```
SSLConfig sslConfig = new SSLConfig();
```

until that line:

```
System.out.println("Jersey app started. Try out " + BASE_URI + "\nHit CTRL + C to stop it...");
```

However I get that error:

```
com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain executeProtocolFilter
SEVERE: ProtocolChain exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.newSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:331)
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.obtainSSLEngine(SSLReadFilter.java:378)
    at com.sun.grizzly.filter.SSLReadFilter.execute(SSLReadFilter.java:147)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:136)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:103)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:89)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:67)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How can I write a code that just needs basic authentication at grizzly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about a bug at grizzly. Any ideas about to overcome that bug is welcome. However a tricky solution is here:

http://grizzly.1045725.n5.nabble.com/Grizzly-2-Guice-Jersey-tp5709778p5709787.html